# Spring MVC: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a Spring MVC project where I have set up a simple controller with two request mappings to navigate to JSP pages. However, when I click on the links in my index.jsp, I'm encountering a 404 error. I've double-checked my code and configuration but can't seem to find the issue.

Here's an overview of my project structure and code:

Project Structure:

index.jsp is located in the root of my web application.
add.jsp and addFinal.jsp are located in /WEB-INF/jsp/ within my project.

addController (addController.java):

```
package com.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class addController {
    @RequestMapping("/firstAdd")
    public String add(){
        return "add.jsp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/secondFinal")
    public String addFinal(){
        return "addFinal";
    }
}
```

web.xml Servlet Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">  
    
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Spring MVC Configuration (mvc-servlet.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
       xsi:schemaLocation="  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> 

    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc" />
        
    <!-- Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    
    <!-- Define Spring mvc view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Issue: When clicking on either of the links in index.jsp, I get a 404 error with the URL http://localhost:8080/spring_MVC_project/firstAdd.
[Here is an image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c70I7.png)

I've already checked for common issues like typos, case sensitivity, and the placement of JSP files. Is there anything I'm missing or any specific configuration issue that could lead to this 404 error?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which spring version are you using? Which server (I assume Tomcat) version are you using?

Comment: I using tomcat 9.0 version

Comment: spring is 5.2.25 and tomcat is 9.0

Comment: Remove `.jsp` from the return of your controller. It will now resolve to `/WEB-INF/jsp/add.jsp.jsp`.

Comment: I tried alr it totally not work

Comment: Then you aren't building and using the code as presented here. Which probably means this is a watered down version of what you are actually using? Or the file structure isn't as you are showing here. In shor tthere is thus too little information here.

Comment: "Oh, I've identified the issue. I'll provide an update in my response. The file com.mvc.addController.java was placed in the wrong package. It should be located in src/main/java, but I mistakenly placed it in src/main/resources. This is the reason it couldn't be scanned as a @Controller.

Answer (score 0):

YEAH, I have found the solution for my question, and if You got the same problem or issue like this, just check your package

There are nothing wrong with my code but the package was wrong

The file com.mvc.addController.java It should be located in

```
src/main/java
```

but I mistakenly placed it in

```
src/main/resources
```

This is the reason it couldn't be scanned as a @Controller."

Thank You everyone